# Implementing Conway's Game of Life

Tags: c++, c++11, game-of-life

Here is an implementation of Conway's Game of Life. My code is working fine but I want you to review and give me your suggestions of how to improve it.

These are the steps of my code:

1. Initialize the grid cells with zeros (all cells are dead at the start)
2. Then randomly change some of the grid cells to one (bring some cells to life)
3. Draw the grid
4. Update the grid, by checking which cells are going to live or die
5. Go to step 3

**gameOfLife.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_OF_LIFE_H
#define GAME_OF_LIFE_H

#include <vector>
#include <random>

class gameOfLife
{
public:
    typedef std::vector< std::vector<int>> gridVector;

private:
    int gridSize;
    gridVector mainGrid;
    gridVector *gridCopy;

public:
    gameOfLife();

public:     
    void run();
    void initGrid();
    void drawGrid();
    void updateGrid();
    void copyGrid ();
    int checkNeighbors(gridVector *grid, int x, int y);
    void nextGeneration(int x, int y, int lod);
    int randGenerate(int start, int end);

private:     
    std::random_device randDevice;
    std::mt19937 gen;
};



#endif
```

**implementation.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gameOfLife.h";

gameOfLife::gameOfLife() : gridSize(15), gen(randDevice())
{
}

void gameOfLife::initGrid()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
        {
            mainGrid[i].push_back(0);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < gridSize ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < gridSize ; j++)
        {
            int randSize     = randGenerate(2 , gridSize);
            int state       = randGenerate(0 , 2);
            int indexRow    = randGenerate(1, randSize );
            int indexColumn = randGenerate(1, randSize );

            mainGrid[indexColumn][indexRow] = state;
        }
    }
}

int gameOfLife::randGenerate(int start, int end)
{
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> genenNum(start, end - 1);

        return genenNum(gen);
}

void gameOfLife::drawGrid()
{
    char ch = 254;
    for(int i = 1; i < gridSize - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < gridSize - 1; j++)
        {

                if(mainGrid[i][j])
                {
                    std::cout << " "<<ch;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "  ";
                }

        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

void gameOfLife::copyGrid ()
{
    gridCopy = &mainGrid;
    (*gridCopy).resize(gridSize);
}

void gameOfLife::updateGrid()
{
    copyGrid();

    for(int i = 1; i < gridSize - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < gridSize - 1; j++)
        {
            int lod = checkNeighbors(gridCopy, i, j);    
            nextGeneration( i, j, lod);

        }

    }
}

int gameOfLife::checkNeighbors(gridVector *gridCopy, int x, int y)
{
    int lod = 0;
     for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
     {
         for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
         {
             if(!(i == 0 && j == 0))
             {
                 if((*gridCopy)[ x + i ][ y + j ]) 
                 {
                     lod++;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     return lod;
}

void gameOfLife::nextGeneration(int x, int y, int lod)
{
    if(lod < 2) 
    {
        mainGrid[x][y] = 0;
    }
    else if(lod == 3)
    {
        mainGrid[x][y] = 1;
    }
    else if(lod > 3)
    {
        mainGrid[x][y] = 0;
    }
}

void gameOfLife::run()
{
    mainGrid.resize(gridSize);

    initGrid();

    while(true)
    {       
        drawGrid();
        updateGrid();       
        system("cls");
    }
}

int main()
{
    gameOfLife gol;
    gol.run();

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `#include`s should not end with a semicolon:

  > ```
  > #include "gameOfLife.h";
  > ```

  The reason this is incorrect is because this is a preprocessor directive, which do not follow the same syntax as compiled lines.
- Instead of using a `typedef`:

  > ```
  > typedef std::vector< std::vector<int>> gridVector;
  > ```

  you can now use C++11's [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

  ```
  using std::vector<std::vector<int>> = gridVector;
  ```
- If you don't need the default constructor, you can either leave it out or make it [explicitly defaulted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

  ```
  gameOfLife() = default;
  ```
- There's really no need for multiple `public` and `private` sections.  If you prefer to organize or separate the members in some way, you can just add line breaks.
- I'm not sure why you have a `*gridCopy` member.  Not only would it be more natural to use a copy constructor in such cases, but having a raw pointer as a member would "force" you to have an overloaded copy constructor.  This is because the default copy constructor performs shallow copies, which will copy the *pointer* instead of the value at that pointer.

  After removing this member, you should also remove `copyGrid()`.
- I'm not too familiar with GoL, but I don't think that `while` loop in `run()` is supposed to run infinitely.  This type of `while` loop will *not* stop unless a `break` or `return` is encountered.  You may need to modify it in such a way that it can end.

Comment: I can't use _using_ as my compiler doesn't understand and when I try to to make the default constructor default the compiler says _pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function_.

Comment: @Code_LOVER: Some C++11 compilers actually don't support it, and you should be able to check which ones support which feature.  You can just stick with `typedef` and leave out the default constructor if it's not needed; no problem.

Comment: @Jamal: _#includes should not end with a semicolon_ but they may. It is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: @vnp: If so, could you direct me to an explanation?  I cannot find one anywhere.  Also, after testing it myself, my compiler gives a warning.

Comment: @Jamal: _#include <foo>_ is a textual substitution. Assume it is C++ text valid per se. If it is followed by a semicolon, the semicolon would represent an empty statement, still valid. I am not sure I can point a chapter and verse. PS: there are sick cases (two sequential #includes not valid on their own) when my assertion doesn't hold.

Comment: @Jamal: Chapter and verse, I believe, is 6.2(1) of a latest draft Standard (https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) as well as similar paragraphs of earlier Standards, which explains that _expression_statement_ is _optional expression_ followed by a semicolon. What is an exact nature of a warning you are given?

Comment: @vnp: [unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzk5a1hy.aspx)

Comment: @vnp So is `std::cout << "hy";;;;;;;;;;` or `;; std::cout << "hy" ;;` but that doesn't mean it is OK to write code like that. Jamal comment stating that `#include` directives shouldn't end with a semicolon is perfectly valid. Same applies for macros or other preprocessing commands, loops (exception being do...while) conditionals, namespaces or anonymous scopes.

Comment: @Memleak: I stand corrected, although still looking for the right place in the Standard.

Answer (score 3):

Correctness: `gridCopy` is a pointer to `mainGrid`. Both names alias same data. No data is copied by `gridCopy = &mainGrid` assignment. Every change made by `nextGeneration` (allegedly on `mainGrid`) is visible through `gridCopy`. Which means the code doesn't implement Game of Life in Conway's sense. You need to create a real copy.

I'd also question a `gridCopy` being a class member. It is passed down as an argument to `checkNeighbors`, which in turn is only called from `updateGrid`. `gridCopy` is actually calculated by the latter and is not needed anywhere else. It is better be a `updateGrid` local.

PS: `system(cls)` resulted in (an expected) runtime error on my linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jamal and @vnp for your help. After taking your suggestions into consideration I have made some changes to my code. First I have updated my `copyGrid()` method so that it can now make a real copy.

```
void gameOfLife::copyGrid()
{
    (*gridCopy).clear();
    (*gridCopy).resize(gridSize);

    for(int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
        {
            (*gridCopy)[i].push_back((*mainGrid)[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, I add a new method called `swap()` which swaps the `gridCopy` and `mainGrid` vectors at the end of every iteration.

```
void gameOfLife::swap()
{
    gridVector *temp = mainGrid;
    mainGrid = gridCopy;
    gridCopy = temp;
}
```

And finally, instead of running the program in an infinite loop, now the user can decide on the number of generations to do.

```
int generation = 500;
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < generation; i++)
{   
    drawGrid();
    updateGrid();
    system("cls");
}
```

And as you guys said `system("cls")` is not a good way to clear the screen, I am now in the middle of implementing my own and will post it when it is complete.

Comment: I don't think you need a separate `swap()` function.  There is already a [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function that will do the same thing, and probably in a safer manner.